# MSSQL & ColdFusion Encryption conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, coldfusion, cfml

I am able to encrypt data using ColdFusion using 3DES (and other algorithms). I am also able to encrypt data using MSSQL 3DES (`encryptByPassPhrase`) and `EncryptByKey`.

Is it possible to encrypt data in ColdFusion using 3DES (or any algorithm), then decrypt the data in MSSQL? 
Similarly, Is it possible to encrypt data in MSSQL then decrypt the data in ColdFusion?

Ian.

Comment: Do you want to compare the passwords?

Comment: How are you trying to decrypt in MSSQL? And what is your use case for it? The SQL Server engine should handle encryption and decryption on its end and then hand it to ColdFusion, though I believe you can encrypt a column, hand the encrypted data to CF and decrypt it. Encryption in SQL Server is handled with a certificate created on the SQL Server itself. So there may be a bit of additional config to work with. Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Shawn - Does SQL Server actually have the option to pass in an enc key, like CF? I'm a little foggy on it, but I thought it generated a key for you, based on a password. So not sure you can match the results in CF if you don't the key SQL Server used.

Comment: @Ageax I believe you can create a key in SQL server and then use it when you do the encryption or create a certificate. I _think_ it can be shared between the two systems, though it would take some testing and playing around to get it done. I'm not sure what the use is here, but I believe it is possible. You would have to know the key that was used in SQL Server to do the encryption. Again though, it would be so much easier to only work with it on one of the systems. Again, my question would be "What is the ultimate goal here?"

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you are using SQL2016+, then all encryption algorithms except AES(128/192/256) are deprecated. 3DES is slow and less secure than AES. Is there a reason for using 3DES?

Comment: @Shawn - Yeah, the ability to share and "know" the key was what I was getting at. I was under the impression SQL Server derived the key, and that it wasn't exposed (not 100% on that). But like you said, I too am curious about the use case first...

Comment: @Ageax I _think_ there are methods inside SQL Server that allow a key to be set and used, but I'm not 100% sure. SQL encryption can get very complex very quickly. And honestly I think that encrypting in SQL and encrypting in CF, while ultimately doing the same, are two different means to a couple of ends. And there really needs to be a question of what level of security is actually needed. A person's SSN needs much stronger encryption than the state they live in.

Comment: Thanks folks. My use case is that I want to potentially use CF ORM and do the encryption at this level and then save the encrypted value into the MSSQL. I can currently do the encryption using a cfquery tag with TSQL inside it but I'd like to be able to use ORM and just save the encrypted value here. We're using the encryptByPassPhrase / decryptByPassPhrase methods in MSSQL and within CF cfquery tags.
@Shawn - thanks for pointing out the deprecation of all but AES. I was unaware of this. Perhaps encryption of AES in CF and MSSQL may produce the same result?
I'm on MSSQL 2012 and CF 2016

Comment: Are you using the data on more than one system or is it only going into CF? Regardless, it would probably be better to do encryption on the app server and store that encrypted value in the db. If you need additional db-level encryption, then use SQL2012+'s TDE (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/bb934049(v=sql.110)). But again, the question goes back to what level of encryption do you actually need? CF encryption helps in-transit. You're never passing plaintext values around. TDE helps if your drive is stolen (and requires no special coding, just setup).

Comment: And if you're going to use CF ORM to pass values around, I'd recommend you encrypt in CF and ultimately store that encrypted value. On 2012, you're OK to keep using 3DES, but when you upgrade, you'll have to change it. Besides, AES is better than 3DES.

Comment: Hi @Shawn. Thanks for the detailed answer below. The type of data I'm encrypting is every text value in the DB; User data, company data etc. Basically we want the full DB encrypted. 
I know I can encrypt in CF and then store in DB but the problem then is trying to do SQL queries on this data. A simple use-case is trying to do a SQL like search on a company name for example. I want to be able to decrypt in TSQL and apply the like where clause with a company name. If I can't decrypt in SQL I can't do these kind of of searches.
It seems that there is no matching encryption options so.

Comment: I'm just using the data in CF and MSSQL

Comment: Are you encrypting to protect the data in case someone is intercepting your web requests or are you trying to protect the data if someone steals your database?

Comment: If concern is snooping, use CF. If it's a stolen database, do it with SQL's encryption mechanisms.

Comment: Q. Are you encrypting to protect the data in case someone is intercepting your web requests or are you trying to protect the data if someone steals your database?

A. Both

Comment: Is this PII information? I'd look into SSL/TLS for in-transit data and SQL TDE for at-rest data. SSL/TLS will keep someone from seeing what you're sending, and TDE will protect against a stolen drive or stolen backups. https://letsencrypt.org/ & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/bb934049(v=sql.110)

Comment: Also, are you worried about an internal employee being able to see data in the database? Protecting that can be accomplished with SQL's encryption options and database access permissions.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it should be a simple problem, but as I said above, encryption gets very complex very quickly.

My short answer for this specific situation is "Likely Not". There is a difference in the way CF's `encrypt()` and SQL's `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` work. Even if you use the same passphrase, they won't encrypt to the value. Even `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` uses some magic underneath its hood when it encrypts the value. It's a non-deterministic function, which means that given the same input, the output may be different. Example: Try running `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(N'secretkey',N'myEncryptedValue1')' 5 times. You will get 5 different values.`DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` is smart enough to know SQL Server's method of key derivation and encryption, so it will be able to decrypt the value given the proper key.

A few things to note here:

1) `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` returns a `varbinary(8000)` datatype. And `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` will also return a `varbinary(8000)`. To get a readable value, you'll have to `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` the value back to a `nvarchar()`.

2) `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` only accepts `char`, `binary` and their `N` and `var` types. So if you want to encrypt any other type, you'll have to `cast/convert` it to binary.

3) This uses 3DES, which is slow and not as secure as the "newer" AES. DES is insecure, and 3DES is essentially DES run 3 times. There are better encryption algorithms available. And since 3DES will be deprecated past SQL2016, I'm guessing that `ENCRYPT/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` will also be deprecated or changed. Also, AES, while pretty secure, is almost 20 years old.

4) `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` runs its passphrase through a non-published key derivation function to generate a 128-bit key. This is my main reason for thinking that you won't be able to go back and forth between CF and SQL if you use `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()`. There's simply no reliable way to regenerate the actual key used to encrypt the value.

I ran a couple of tests to demonstrate some of what I said above:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f6ca9aab4dc6f7484d1b332797d1e0d5)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (enc varbinary(8000));
>
> DECLARE @secretKey Nvarchar(20) = N'secretkey' ;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 
> VALUES
>     (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@secretKey, N'myEncryptedValue1'))
>   , (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@secretKey, N'myEncryptedValue2'))
>   , (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@secretKey, N'myEncryptedValue3'))
>   , (ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@secretKey, N'myEncryptedValue4'))
> ;
> ```
>
> Let's decrypt what we've entered.
>
> ```
> SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(N'secretkey',enc)) FROM t1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)  |
> | :---------------- |
> | myEncryptedValue1 |
> | myEncryptedValue2 |
> | myEncryptedValue3 |
> | myEncryptedValue4 |
> ```
>
> Using `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()`, we can decrypt the value on different SQL Servers. It doesn't rely on the server's certificates to do the encryption.

Now let's show that `EncryptByPassphrase()` is non-deterministic.

> ```
> TRUNCATE TABLE t1;
>
> /* Are we empty? */
> SELECT * FROM t1 ; 
>
> |       enc        |
> | No rows returned |
>
> /* Insert the same value multiple times, encrypted. */
> INSERT INTO t1 
> VALUES 
>     ( ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('secretkey','myEncryptedValue1') ) 
>   , ( ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('secretkey','myEncryptedValue1') )
>   , ( ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('secretkey','myEncryptedValue1') ) 
>   , ( ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('secretkey','myEncryptedValue1') ) 
>   , ( ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('secretkey','myEncryptedValue1') )
> ;
>
> /* Do all rows encrypt to the same value? */
> SELECT * FROM t1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | enc                                                                                        |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 0x01000000FE4E975E32AF37B6EB2E497C76C3404ED8C06E1264DCE96C1753B89812636BFE28581DA788046994 |
> | 0x010000008A684062BFF1A63FC86FFDE508CA30A5130BD51459DAFD9B18CF5DD0E7775D90BC80574953C26161 |
> | 0x01000000084828F7D3E2053D9E13B45B9C42A34242F6ECF5D6A9DC934EA9EE10F3BD2CFB61AA1C9EBC8DB97E |
> | 0x0100000083A4E21C5F5BD8CBE65CA83DEB4A46F58D1F74768760EC28C3836E1F285E65E289A6EFB6428BD738 |
> | 0x01000000DFEA8A52F63726D93E4561A19CEEFD427460E0B8617BE6633210DFFF43DD4DD083DF4CF4CB85F129 |
> ```
>
> That's the same value encrypted with `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` multiple times, but resulting in 5 different values. This shows that there's some magic going on behind the scenes in SQL. There's no way we can decrypt that value in ColdFusion, because we don't know the key derivation that happened before the encryption occurred.

Now, all of that said, my longer answer to your question of "Can you share encryption between CF and SQL?" would be "It depends."

Clearly using SQL's `ENCRYPT/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` won't work with CF, since there's no real way to reliably know the derived key used to encrypt the values. However, there are numerous ways to skin the encryption cat. And again, the main question that you'll need to answer for yourself is "What type of data am I trying to protect?". That will tell you what types of encryption you'll ultimately need.

And since I've already spent this many characters just briefly touching on just a couple of functions in just one of the technologies you're using, I think this goes full circle back to my original point that encryption gets very complex very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I'm aware of how EncryptByPassphrase() works with it being non-deterministic etc. I'm just trying to find a matching encryption/decryption algorithm between CF and MSSQL. Seems it does not exist.

Comment: It's not the algorithm that's the issue. It's the black box key derivation that `EncryptByPassphrase()` does. There are probably ways to do it with certificate-based encryption, but I'm not sure how it can be handled it your situation. `ENCRYPT/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` may not be the method to use. And if you're wanting the fields to be searchable, you may not need the encryption on them. SQL Server encryption may be what you're looking for in that case.

Comment: *"Seems it does not exist.*" From what I've read, that's my impression too. It's probably not possible using "keys". Say CF use key = "abc" and AES128. Even if SQL Server is using AES128 too, it doesn't actually use "abc" as the key. SQL Server treats it as a passphrase, and somehow *derives* a key by transforming "abc" it into some other value - and that "other" value is what's used as the encryption key. Since that whole process is a black box method, there's no way of easily knowing what "key" SQL Server ultimately uses, making it impossible to duplicate the results in CF.